# Cxf Wsdl2java null entry in list disappear

Tags: jaxb, cxf, jax-ws, wsdl2java, jaxb-xew-plugin

I've created a webservice client with cxf with the [xew plugin](https://github.com/dmak/jaxb-xew-plugin) for list unwrapping

The problem is that the `null` in the list disappear.
E.g.:

I have an Request with a `List<String>` with Strings and a `null`-entry

When the request now arrives at the server it only contains the Strings not the `null` entry. So there are only 2 entries in the example list.

Here a example of the wsdl:

```xml
[..]
<!-- the request -->
<xsd:element name="createGroup">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="in0" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="in1" nillable="true" type="ns2:ArrayOfRole"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
[..]
<!-- the list which will be unwrapped -->
<xsd:complexType name="ArrayOfRole">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="Role" nillable="true" type="xsd:String"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

I'm using maven to generate the ws client

```xml
<properties>
    <cxf.version>3.0.5</cxf.version>
    <jaxbBasic.version>0.6.5</jaxbBasic.version>
</properties>
[..]
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <sourceRoot>src/main/java</sourceRoot>
                <defaultOptions>
                    <bindingFiles>
                        <bindingFile>${basedir}/jaxbBindings.xml</bindingFile>
                        <bindingFile>${basedir}/jaxwsBindings.xml</bindingFile>
                    </bindingFiles>
                    <extraargs>
                        <!-- xew plugin for unwrapping list wrappers types NOTE: the args need to be over the others otherwise there are compilation errors -->
                        <extraarg>-xjc-Xxew</extraarg>
                        <extraarg>-xjc-Xxew:instantiate lazy</extraarg>

                        <!-- Generate toString, equals, hashcode methods -->
                        <extraarg>-xjc-Xts:style:de.company.tostring.CustomToStringStyle.DEFAULT</extraarg>
                        <extraarg>-xjc-Xequals</extraarg>
                        <extraarg>-xjc-XhashCode</extraarg>
                    </extraargs>
                </defaultOptions>
                <wsdlRoot>${ws.dirAbsolute}</wsdlRoot>
                <includes>
                    <include>*.wsdl</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf.xjcplugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-xjc-ts</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxbBasic.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.jaxb-xew-plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-xew-plugin-fixed</artifactId> <!-- this is a custom version with a small modification see https://github.com/dmak/jaxb-xew-plugin/issues/44 -->
            <version>1.7-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

jaxbBindings.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxb:bindings version="2.1" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb">
    <jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false"/>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

jaxwsBindings.xml

```xml
<jaxws:bindings xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
            xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
            xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb">
    <jaxws:enableWrapperStyle>false</jaxws:enableWrapperStyle>
</jaxws:bindings>
```

A sample request:

```
final CreateGroup create = new CreateGroup();
create.setIn0("newgroup");
final List<String> roles = new ArrayList<String>();
roles.add("testrole");
roles.add(null);
roles.add("testrole2");
create.setIn1(roles);
final SamplePortType proxy = ..;
proxy.createGroup(create);
```

Is there a way that the `null` entry is still be present at the serverside?

Comment: You should post your plugin configuration and a sample request.

Comment: @approxiblue I've added sample code and my configuration.

Comment: May be setting minOccurs="1" for  ArrayOfRole complex type can help ?

Comment: @cacert no, the fault is from cxf not the wsdl (i think), with axis all works well. and as in this example the user could have no groups. so 0 is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the [`jaxb-xew-plugin`](https://github.com/dmak/jaxb-xew-plugin) generates code that misses `nillable = true`
for the `XmlElement` of the List.

Generated by the plugin:

```java
@XmlElementWrapper(required = true, nillable = true)
@XmlElement(name = "Role", namespace = "http://www.stackoverflow.com/example")
protected List<String> in1;
```

If you try, with added `nillable=true`, it will work:

```java
@XmlElementWrapper(required = true, nillable = true)
@XmlElement(name = "Role", namespace = "http://www.stackoverflow.com/example", nillable = true)
protected List<String> in1;
```

So it seems the plugin is missing the `nillable` attribute for wrapped values.

I think the problem lies in [this code part](https://github.com/dmak/jaxb-xew-plugin/blob/ed7b1c81366e7d812735ef0e295c8f63b0b3c204/src/main/java/com/sun/tools/xjc/addon/xew/XmlElementWrapperPlugin.java#L595), where the XmlElement is "lifted" to an outer element and the `nillable` attribute is left out.

Adding the following code snippet to the mentioned code part will solve your problem and generate working code:

```java
JExpression nillable = getAnnotationMemberExpression(xmlElementOriginalAnnotation, "nillable");
if (nillable != null) {
    xmlElementAnnotation.param("nillable", nillable);
}
```

The problem discussed in this question is solved as of **version 1.7** of the jaxb-xew-plugin. [This issue](https://github.com/dmak/jaxb-xew-plugin/issues/45) keeps track of that case, [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.github.jaxb-xew-plugin%22%20AND%20a%3A%22jaxb-xew-plugin%22) are the releases.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this, but could it be that the `generateElementProperty` in the JAXB bindings may be causing the issue? According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/820-1072/ahiid/index.html), if that property is set to false, JAXB won't be able to roundtrip all XML documents. If set to true, you'll have to deal with `JAXBElement` class but, as the documentation says:

> The JAXBElement type roundtrips the XML representation of name element across an unmarshal/marshal operation.

Check the examples in that page, it may help.